# Plot date labels in x-axis [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

I have a plot with dates in form of `mm/dd` as x-axis data. Now I have

```
xData = ["01/22"    "01/23"    "01/24"    "01/25"    "01/26"    "01/27"    "01/28"    "01/29"]
```

which is a **string array** of size `1 x 8`.

How do I plot with

```
yData = [557         655         941        1433        2118        2927        5578        6167]
```

by using something like

```
plot(xData, yData)
```

with `["01/22"    "01/23"    "01/24"    "01/25"    "01/26"    "01/27"    "01/28"    "01/29"]` as the x-axis tick labels?

Currently I got the error messages `Error using plot. Not enough input arguments.` when running `plot(xData, yData)` as above, which I don't know what it exactly means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. Convert the xData into a datetime array and use it in the plot

   ```
   plot(datetime(xData, 'InputFormat', 'MM/dd', 'Format', 'MM/dd'), yData)
   ```
2. Use xData as the label of the x axis:

   ```
    plot(yData)
    set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(yData), 'XTickLabel', xData)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`plot(datetime(xData, 'InputFormat', 'MM/dd', 'Format', 'MM/dd'), yData)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).